# Katalon- Parallel execution of multiple browsers through cmd

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

Through Katalon studio UI tool we are able to perform parallel execution of test suites in test suite collection for different browsers.

Problem: Same approach is not working when we tried through cmd. Below is the command for the same:

```
katalon -noSplash  -runMode=console -projectPath="<projectPath>" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="<testSuitePath>" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Chrome,IE"
```

Note: Works fine for single browser as parameter

Please let us know if above command is correct for multiple browser execution

Expected :

Single report folder containing parallel execution results of both the browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, by using Test Suite Collections.

You put your TC1 (test case) in TS1 (test suite). My test case is called "proba" in this example. Then you create a TSC1 (test suite collection) and you add the same test suite **twice** to the collection. See screenshot. And change "Run with" parameter to Chrome and IE, respectively.

[image]

If you now create a command line argument, you will get something like

```
katalon -noSplash  -runMode=console -consoleLog -projectPath="C:\\Katalon Studio\PROJECT NAME\PROJECT NAME.prj" -retry=0 -testSuiteCollectionPath="Test Suites/TEST SUITE COLLECTION 1"
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Mate :) Solution worked for me